# Error in java.library.path when calling a Java function that uses Cplex, from Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, jar, cplex

I would like to call a Java function that uses Cplex, from Matlab.
At the moment, I am stuck. Below is a list of things I tried, but I am out of ideas. Before I get there, let me list the versions:

1. Matlab version 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
2. Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
3. Eclipse with jre7 and jdk1.7.0_79

I created a package "milp.jar" and try to call the following function from Matlab:

```
milp.MTsolver.Plan()
```

In a basic version of my milp.jar, without any Cplex functionality, this goes without problems. Just as soon as I use a Cplex function in my Java class, I get in trouble. I tried the following:

To be able to use Cplex, I added the path to the javaclasspath.txt file in the Matlab folder

```
prefdir
```

The command

```
javaclasspath
```

in Matlab console indeed shows that this path is added to the Static Java Path.
But then, when calling my cplex dependent function milp.MTsolver.Plan(), I get the following error:

```
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no cplex1262 in java.library.path
java.library.path must point to the directory containing the CPLEX shared library
try invoking java with java -Djava.library.path=...
```

Following this [post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014587785), I should first load the library:

```
java.lang.System.load('C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1262\cplex\lib\cplex.jar');
```

But this gives the following error:

```
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1262\cplex\lib\cplex.jar: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

At his point, I tried another approach. I just copied the cplex.jar into the Matlab root folder. No success. Nor any succes when just copying the cplex.jar in the project folder in Matlab.

Then, I tried to find a cplex1262.jar, but I only found a cplex1262.dll. So I added this path to the Static Java Path. This gives the following error:

```
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXopenCPLEX([I)J
```

The same error occurs when I run the following in the Matlab console:

```
java.lang.System.load('C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1262\opl\oplide\plugins\ilog.odms.ide.opllang.win32.win32.x86_64_12.6.2.0\cplex1262.dll');
```

A last thing I could try comes from an answer in this [post](http://itquestionz.com/questions/2011498/combine-cplex-and-java).
Here, he sets

```
-Djava.library.path=...
```

in the VM Options field, but in Netbeans. I could try to do something similar in Matlab, but I have not figured out yet how. 
Last, I just added the directories containing cplex.jar and cplex1262.dll to the PATH environment variable. No luck there either.

Another important note might be that I have no problem running my code in Eclipse, including Cplex functionality! It might also be worth mentioning that, in between changes, I restarted Matlab to be sure that all changes in path settings took effect.

I hope to have stated my problem clearly enough. Any suggestions on how to proceed are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a quick and dirty solution, which is ok for now.
First I tried to add the path to the directory containing cplex1262.dll to the 
'java.library.path' as follows:

```
java.lang.System.setProperty('java.library.path', [path to dir])
```

But that did not work for me. In a quick and dirty manner, I looked up what paths were already included in this property, with the following command.

```
>> java.lang.System.getProperty('java.library.path')

ans =

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\sys\jxbrowser\win64\lib
```

And just copy/pasted the cplex1262.dll in the \lib directory.

That worked.